# Apple software update was stuck at downloading now its stuck at cancelling

Tags: software-update

I got a notification to update the itunes v12.2.1.Initially had lots of download going on so the download was slow.Later after completing the  windows downloads the itunes update is simpply stuck at one place it doesn't resume the download.
[image: Apple Software Update stuck the download at 51.70MB]

When I start another download it starts downloading very fast but when I see the same for itunes the update doesn't resume it is stuck at 51.70MB

A few while later as it was still stuck on that 51.70 I clicked the Stop but now even the cancelling is stuck.

Although I can simply open the task manager and closed it but why exactly did the software update didn't resume when it had the free bandwidth for updating

[image]

Comment: reboot computer & router. Navigate to %localappdata%\Apple\Apple Software Update [you can copy/paste that into the start menu, including both % & it will take you straight there]& delete the partial file, if one is there.

Comment: Or download the latest iTunes from http://Tunes.com

Comment: @Tetsujin there are 2 files namely itunes6464.msi which is a windows installer and the Setup Admin.exe which is an application.Did the restart as well and again the same thing now stuck at 13.20 MB

Comment: delete both, if you didn't already & try again

Answer (score 2):

For my situation, none of these solutions worked for Windows 10. I resolved it by going to the iTunes site, download and run the full iTunes install, rather than just the update.